# Issue generating resources in VS.Net 2010, windows 7 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, x86-64, resx

I am having an issue generating resources in VS.Net 2010, windows 7 64bit. It am able to compile the solution in Visual studio. But when I try to compile the solution in command prompt using msbuild, it fails generating the resources.

I went through the below link and find a solution to get it compiled in command prompt using msbuild.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/19/resgen-exe-error-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format.aspx

I used option 2 from the above article.

Before compiling in command prompt I have to execute the below two commands.

```
CorFlags /32BIT+ /Force Resgen.exe
set RESGENTOOLARCHITECTURE=Managed32Bit
```

And after finishing the compilation I have to execute the below remove 32 bit command. Other wise it fails in visual studio.

```
CorFlags /32BIT- /Force Resgen.exe
```

One weird thing is non of my team members are having any issue with this. I only have the problem.

Could you please let me know why it's only me?

Also any other permanent solution if you have, with out running the above commands again and again.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it has issues with the privileges.

Just make sure that you have tried running your command prompt with full privileges.

i.e. Run as administrator